# Numpy 3D array Indexing : Works for 2D, how to do for 3D?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 3 `numpy` arrays as given below.

```py
import numpy as np
key_idx = np.array([1, 2, 1])  # both have same shape
out_idx = np.array([0, 3, 0])
max_out = out_idx.max()
output = np.zeros(shape=(len(key_idx), max_out + 1))

# output = 
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I want to increment the values given by the indices as given below:

```py
key_idx = key_idx[np.newaxis, :] # convert to 2D
out_idx = out_idx[np.newaxis, :]
idx = (key_idx, out_idx)
np.add.at(output, idx, 1)

# output =
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [2., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

And then apply a transformation as follows:

```py
np.sum(np.amax(output, axis=1))
#3.0
```

But now I want to do it for a 3D output array, where `key_idx2D` is a 2D array with the first dimension representing `table_id`. Please refer to the figure below:
[image]

*What I tried*

```py
key_idx2D = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]])
output3D = np.zeros(shape=(key_idx2D.shape[0], len(key_idx), max_out + 1))
key_idx2D = key_idx[np.newaxis, :] # convert to 3D
out_idx = out_idx[np.newaxis, :]
idx3D = (key_idx2D, out_idx)
np.add.at(output3D, idx3D, 1)

#IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

How can I do this for the 3D case? Any help is appreciated. It should return an array of values for each `table_id` as shown in the figure.

*Note*: I can do it with loops, but it will be slow. I need something faster.

**Edit** : 
`key_idx2D` has `axis 0 = table_id` and `axis 1 = key_id`.
`out_idx` has `axis 0 = out_id`.
Both `key_idx2D` and `out_idx` contain the only those indices of `output` ndarray that need to have `np.add.at()` applied on them.
I have updated the figure to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer in case someone finds it useful.

```
key_idx2D = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]])
output3D = np.zeros(shape=(key_idx2D.shape[0], key_idx2D.shape[1], max_out + 1))
output3D.shape
#(2, 3, 4)
```

All I needed was to create an index array for the first axis (i.e., axis 0).

```
table_idx = np.array([0, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)
out_idx = np.array([0, 3, 0])
table_idx.shape, key_idx2D.shape, out_idx.shape
#((2, 1), (2, 3), (3,))
```

Then send all the index arrays to `np.add.at` in the form of a tuple.

```
np.add.at(output3D, (table_idx, key_idx2D, out_idx), 1)
output3D

# array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
#         [2., 0., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 0., 1.]],
#        [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 0., 0.],
#         [2., 0., 0., 1.]]])

np.sum(np.amax(output3D, axis=2), axis=1)
#array([3., 2.])
```